# How to fetch child node inside nested firebase DB

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

[image]

Hi,I was to fetch only the nodes where category = "Tribal" and return it as firebase array object.Thanks in advance.

### Angular Service CODE:

```
this.getSpecialTourPackage = function(){
 var dbRef = firebase.database().ref('states').child('itineraries');
 return $firebaseArray(dbRef);
};
```

### Angular Controller CODE:

```
if(_category != undefined && _category == 'Tribal'){
    var loadedResult = [];
    var resultArray = indiaTourService.getSpecialTourPackage();
    resultArray.$loaded().then(function(data){
    data.forEach(item =>{
    loadedResult.push(item);
    $scope.itineraries = _.where(loadedResult,{ category : "Tribal"});
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: `firebase.database().ref('states').child('itineraries');` There is no `/states/itineraries`, so that won't match any nodes.

Comment: If you're trying to query across all itineraries of all states, that is not possible without modifying your data model. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value